# How to start the photo scroller with the selected image from collectionView in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have used the code

```
  imageSlider = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 60, 700, 700)];
    imageSlider.pagingEnabled = YES;
    imageSlider.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =NO;

    for (int i = 0; i < [myObject count]; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = imageSlider.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = imageSlider.frame.size;
        NSManagedObject *con = [myObject objectAtIndex:i] ;
        UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageWithData:[con valueForKey:@"image"]];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 700, 700)];
        imgView.image = Image;
        imgView.frame = frame;
        [imageSlider addSubview:imgView];
    }


     imageSlider.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageSlider.frame.size.width*([myObject count]), 600);
     imageSlider.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:imageSlider];
```

It starts from first image I dono how to start image from the selected image in previous viewController. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have not got clear from your question.